# Common name for Create and Update

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, crud

I have a web-app. I need to Create and Update an item, but since this is almost the very same code (or perhaps even exactly the same code), I am searching for a good name for the combined operation to be used in the url, and I am totally blank. Perhaps "Edit" (it would be very close to Update, but perhaps I am "Editing the text for the new item")?. Maybe there is something better?

I am using AngularJS. Maybe I should use the same code, just with two different routes (that uses the same template and controller)?

Comment: You can also use two different routes(e.g. `/add`, `/edit/:id`) to the same action, but still it's one name of the action for both operations

Comment: This could be formulated as an answer? I would strongly consider accepting it :)

Comment: could be like: edit, save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use two different routes (e.g. `/add`, `/edit/:id`) to the same action, but still it's one name of the action for both operations :)

But if you're using AngularJS you can easily implement RESTful web service integration and I strongly recommend it, if only you can do that.

Comment: What would be the routes for "item" here? Perhaps the following?: To list all items: ..../item/ To view one item: .../item/:id To add a new item: .../item/add To edit an existing item: .../item/edit/:id And should it be "item" or "items" when listing all items?

Comment: Based on "RESTful Service Best Practices" (https://s3.amazonaws.com/tfpearsonecollege/bestpractices/RESTful+Best+Practices.pdf) I'd suggest using plural `items` for all routes. Personally, I use plural because then I can create a tree of URIs, but there is a long debate in that subject...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the RESTful standard (especially good for Angular) recommend to use two endpoints to do all the basic CRUD operations for an entity, with the use of the different http methods (POST, GET, DELETE...) :

For instance

```
POST   .../entity   Create a new entity
GET    .../entity   List of all entities
```

And

```
PUT    .../entity/:id  Update the entity 
DELETE .../entity/:id  Delete the entity
GET    .../entity/:id  Get the details of an entity
```

This way you need only two endpoint but you can still do all your operations thanks to the HTTP standard methods

EDIT:

I misunderstood your question, you are more interested int he url the user will see. 
In this case I would suggest the following :

```
Creation form  /entity
See details    /entity/:id      (maybe even /entity/:id/name_of_entity just for the user sake but no effect on the angular routing)
Update form    /entity/:id/edit
```

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of the web app urls (not endpoints). I was kind of hoping for a common term to be used in the url for what is essentially the same code, but I am starting to understand that there is no such common name...

Comment: On a side-note: you have "entity" in singluar to list all entities. I see some use plural form: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/ Should I just do what I feel like in this matter?

Comment: Yes, nothing is really decided. As long as you maintain a certain consistency in your app you can choose whatever you want, the idea is to avoid to confuse the user by changing between entities.

Comment: @EricC yes, it is one of the most debated point : should we use singular or plural ? . Since the same endpoint can be used for the manipulation of a single object (create) or several (list) then it is difficult to choose